# Compare two vector in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors:`a = c(1,2,3)`, `b = c(1,2,3)`

I want to test whether `a` is exactly the same as `b`. I know the result can be given by `sum(a == b) == length(a)`, but is there any elegant way?

Comment: Could you specify more the "_exactly the same_"? Numeric equality, same R object, attributes? E.g. compare (1) `identical(1, 1 + 1e-14)` VS `all.equal(1, 1 + 1e-14)` VS `(1 == (1 + 1e-14))`, (2) `identical(1, 1L)` VS `all.equal(1, 1L)`, (3) `identical(1, c(a = 1))` VS `all.equal(1, c(a = 1))`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can use `identical`

```
identical(a,b)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or if we there are some difference in attributes which we need to avoid in the comparison, use `all.equal`

```
all.equal(a,b, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using similar approach in the OP's post, we can make it compact with `all`

```
all(a==b)
#[1] TRUE
```

The number of characters in the above approach is less...

```
nchar("identical(a,b)")
#[1] 14
nchar("all(a==b)")
#[1] 9
```

Comment: Nice to know that attribute flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer above; you could also consider the package 'compare'.

```
library(compare)
compareEqual(a,b)#TRUE
```